# Single Remote Desktop session in Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I have a headless server running Windows Server 2003, and administer it via VNC. It is set to auto login to a specific user account.

I want to change to using Remote Desktop/Terminal Services. However, when I log in remotely a new user session is created (in addition to auto logged in session). Essentially I want a remote desktop connection to take over the default session in the computer (how XP does it). Does anyone know how?

P.S. I am NOT after a single remote session, instead a single GLOBAL session :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To logon as the 'console' user (the one to be used for logging in locally) then you use a parameter for mstsc.exe   From a command prompt type in mstsc /h to see the help.  MSTSC /ADMIN /V:YOURSERVERNAME 
or
MSTSC /CONSOLE /V:YOURSERVERNAME

(depending on the version that you have)

Comment: +1 because it's really annoying to have an accepted answer with 0 upvotes :)

Comment: Note that you can combine the /admin or /console switches with the name of an RDP file (if you want to provide other settings, such as TS gateway).

Answer (score 3):

Please excuse the self answer, but for those using OS X and Remote Desktop Connection, all you need to do is append " /console" to the IP address of the computer you wish to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can switch over.

1. Start task manager
2. Switch to the users tab
3. There should be two users listed.  The one you logged on with and the original session you are trying to connect to.
4. Right click on the one you want to connect to and select "Switch" or "connect".  I can't remember the exact one.

Comment: Once again, down voted for a correct answer with no reason.  BTW, this does work :)

Comment: It's "Connect" on Windows 2003. Note that it doesn't let you do this if you're at the physical computer: "#7041 Disconnecting the console session is not supported."

Answer (score 2):

On the server: Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Terminal Services Configuration > Server Settings > Restrict each user to one session

Alternately, you can log in to the console (the session that would display on the monitor, if present).  From XP-era clients, that's (command-line) "mstsc /console /v:host.to.connect.to". For Vista-era clients, it's "mstsc /admin /v:host.to.connect.to".  That option is probably present somewhere in the RDP client settings screen, and tools like [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals) also expose it.